# NDSolve with FEM works on my computer but not on another one I have

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

I have the following code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];


Tinf = 20.0; Tini = 20.0; Lx = 0.10; Lf = 0.01; lx1 = (Lx - Lf)/2;
lx2 = (Lx - Lf)/2 + Lf; ly1 = 0.01;
Lc = 0.001;
ly2 = ly1 + Lc;
ly3 = 0.005;
Ly = ly2 + ly3 ; kep = 0.87; wep = 1400*935;
k1 = 13.4; k2 = 0.7; k3 = 1.171; k4 = 0.0263; 
w1 = 8238*468; w2 = 1750000.0; w3 = 2652321.63;
w4 = 1.1614*1.007*1000; q = 2000; 
tf = 20000.0; 
h = 15.0;
dx = 0.005;

k[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[{{k1, y <= ly1}, {k2, 
     ly1 < y <= ly2 && (x < lx1 || x > lx2)}, {k4, 
     ly1 < y <= ly2 && lx1 <= x <= lx2}, {k3, ly2 < y <= Ly}}];

Cp[x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[{{w1, y <= ly1}, {w2, 
     ly1 < y <= ly2 && (x < lx1 || x > lx2)}, {w4, 
     ly1 < y <= ly2 && lx1 <= x <= lx2}, {w3, ly2 < y <= Ly}}];

eq = Cp[x, y] D[T[x, y, t], t] == 
   D[k[x, y] D[T[x, y, t], x], x] + D[k[x, y] D[T[x, y, t], y], y] + 
    NeumannValue[0., x == Lx] + NeumannValue[0., x == 0] + 
    NeumannValue[q, y == 0] - NeumannValue[h (T[x, y, t] - Tinf), y == Ly];

\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= Ly, {x, y}];

Tn[x_, y_, t_] = 
   NDSolveValue[{eq, T[x, y, 0] == Tini}, 
    T[x, y, t], {t, 0, tf}, {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]; // Timing
```

On my computer (version 11.1) it runs without problems, but I tried to run this same code on another computer (version 11.3) and it gives the following errors when evaluating the last part:

```
NDSolveValue::femtemnm: A mesh could not be generated.

NDSolveValue::fememins: The mesh elements are not valid. A set of valid mesh element
incidents needs to be positive integers and be able to form a complete sequence starting
from 1 to the largest incident present. There are missing incidents; a complete sequence
cannot be formed.

NDSolveValue::nmesh: A mesh could not be generated from
NumericalRegion[ImplicitRegion[0<=x<=0.1&&0<=y<=0.071,{x,y}],{{0,1/10},{0,71/1000}}].
```

I don't have deep knowledge of Mathematica, I just use it to solve some physical problems in engineering.

Can anyone help me, please?

EDIT: with @user21 's idea, the following works:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Lx, Ly}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, 
   "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
```

Comment: In version 12.0 the code runs fine with no warnings or errors. I wonder if the last line is what you intended. In your code it is saving the output of Timing in `Tn`, rather than the output of `NDSolveValue`. You may want `(Tn[...] = NDSolveValue[...]) // Timing` instead (note the parentheses).

Comment: @MarcoB I don't think that was the issue. It didn't work even without the warning. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have version 11.3 installed. But try to use:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Lx, Ly}];
```

And see if that works with V11.3. This will generate a Quad element mesh, which is not a problem. If you rather like Triangle elements you can specify

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01,"MeshElementType"->TriangleElement}}}
```

Comment: Hey! That didn't work, but you gave me an idea and I tried: \[ScriptCapitalR] = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Lx, Ly}], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001, "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement]; It works. Thanks.